# Show that if $X\times X \cong Y \times Y$, then $X\cong Y$

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

This is a question from the book Algebraic Graph Theory, by Godsil and Royle

> Show that if $X\times X \cong Y \times Y$, then $X\cong Y$

Where $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary undirected simple graphs.

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be arbitrary undirected simple graphs, the  product $G_1 \times G_2$ is the graph that has vertex set $V(G_1) \times V(G_2)$, and for every $g, g' \in G_1$ and $h,h'\in G_2$, $(g,h)$ is adjacent to $(g',h')$ if and only if $g$ is adjacent to $g'$ and $h$ is adjacent to $h'$.

---

I feel like I should be able to prove this, but I'm stumped. Can someone provide me with a hint or a proof for this statement?

Comment: Could you be precise about what $X$ and $Y$ are, here? Obviously (for example) you don't mean $X, Y$ are integers, but could you state what they are? Arbitrary graphs?

Comment: Surely the body of your Question allows space to explain what kinds of things $X$ and $Y$ are, e.g. are they sets without any extra structure?   If you can show $X\subset Y$, the same argument will show the reverse inclusion.

Comment: My bad, I've edited the question.

Comment: The question would be improved if you (a) Explain how a graph $G_1 \times G_2$ is defined from the graphs $G_1,G_2.$ and (b) Specify whether your undirected graphs can include loops and/or parallel edges [2 edges joining same two vertices]

Comment: This is true for finite structures in general, not just graphs. It was Tarski's "unique square root" problem and was solved by [László Lovász](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_Lov%C3%A1sz). The proof that I know is by counting homomorphisms.

Comment: Are we assuming the graphs are finite?

Comment: @MarkSaving Quoting from p. 2 of *Algebraic Graph Theory* by Godsil and Royle: "Although the definition of graph allows the vertex set to be infinite, we do not consider this case, and so all our graphs may be assumed to be *finite* — an assumption that is used implicitly in a few of our results." I have added to my answer an example showing that this "unique square root" result can fail for infinite graphs.

Comment: @bof Thanks! It really felt like it shouldn’t hold for infinite graphs. I also really enjoyed looking at the Lovasz result about locally finite categories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graphs are of course assumed to be finite. I believe the result is due to László Lovász, and answered a question originally asked by Alfred Tarski. The argument applies to more general finite structures, e.g., groups. Since you said you would be satisfied with a hint, I omit some details.

Given finite graphs $X$ and $Y$, let $h(X,Y)$ be the number of homomorphisms and $i(X,Y)$ the number of injective homomorphisms from $X$ to $Y$.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are finite graphs with $X\times X\cong Y\times Y$. Then, for any finite graph $Z$, we have
$$h(Z,X)^2=h(Z,X\times X)=h(Z,Y\times Y)=h(Z,Y)^2$$
so $h(Z,X)=h(Z,Y)$ for any finite graph $Z$.

Next, from the fact that $h(Z,X)=h(Z,Y)$ for every finite graph $Z$, it follows that $i(Z,X)=i(Z,Y)$ for every finite graph $Z$. This is the trickiest part of the argument, so I leave it as an exercise for the reader. The argument I know uses the in-and-out formula (also grandiloquently called The Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion), but there may be other and better ways.

In particular, $i(X,Y)=i(X,X)\ge1$ and $i(Y,X)=i(Y,Y)\ge1$. Finally, since the structures are finite, and since there are injective homomorphisms in both directions, those homomorphisms must be isomorphisms.

**P.S.** It's not true for infinite graphs. Writing $+$ for disjoint union of graphs and $\infty G$ for the disjoint union of $\aleph_0$ copies of $G$, let
$$X=\infty K_{1,1}+\infty K_{2,2}+\infty K_{4,4}+\infty K_{8,8}+\cdots+\infty K_{2^n,2^n}+\cdots$$
and
$$Y=\infty K_{1,1}+K_{2,2}+K_{4,4}+K_{8,8}+\cdots+K_{2^n,2^n}+\cdots.$$
Then
$$Y\not\cong X\cong X\times X\cong X\times Y\cong Y\times Y\cong Y\times Y\times Y.$$

Comment: a very nice proof!

Comment: hi bof, this is a nice argument (+1). do you know if the result holds when $X,Y$ are infinite?

Comment: @bof fantastic, thank you so much – nice example!

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I've edited the example into my answer.